# Bootstrap Columns space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Best regards, I need to be able to multiply the right side. And that the left side increases the same height like the right side.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">left</div>

    <div class="col-md-8"> 
        <?php 
           for ($i=0; $i<=10 ; $i++) { 
        ?>
           <p>right</p>
        <?php
           }
        ?>

    </div>
```

When I do this code, the items on the right side are passed to the left side If the left is empty. I need the left side be empty but conserve his space

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KcQv.png)

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution.

```
<div class="row">         
<div class="col-md-3">left</div>
   <div class="col-md-9 main">
      <div class="row">
         <?php 
            for ($i=0; $i<=10 ; $i++) { 
         ?>
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>right</p>
         </div>
         <?php } ?>
    </div> 
 </div>
```